# Is this GET secure to SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql, security

i'm developing a website and i'm asking if this little code is vulnerable to SQL Injection or if it's secure:

```
$param1 = $_GET['param1'];
$sql_news="select * from table1 where attr1 = '$param1'";
```

Can i stay in peace ?

Thanxs

Comment: Terribly insecure.

Comment: Nope. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: The code that you pasted is sql vulnerable...

Comment: If you want know if it's vulnerable or not you just need to learn what a sql injection is.

Comment: Very strictly taken, this is unanswerable. Because you didn't even specify the database type. For a 7bit charset set and given an outdated PHP setup, perhaps; but not very likely. -- How in the world did you come up with this question *again*, though? I find it unlikely that not a single Google search brought up more current tutorials.

Comment: why do you don't use pdo http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: Sorry for the stupid answer and thanxs for the fast replies .. do you know if addslashes() is still vulnerable ?

Comment: @Kiks777 yes, it is. Use parameterized queries... or view the manual -http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php `Please note that use of addslashes() for database parameter escaping can be cause of security issues on most databases.`

Answer (score 1):

No, someone could set `$param1` to, for example, `' OR '1'='1`, which would return the complete content of the table.

Comment: Thanxs for the reply ... i know this vulnerable, but it does not affect this parameter, i don't know why.. is it possible ?

Comment: Ops sorry .. i'm so damn stupid, i understand now why it doesn't works .. sorry mate .. can i ask you if addslash() is vulnerable now? I don't know if the multi-byte vuln has been fixed

Comment: Even with addslash, it would still be vulnerable. The best solution would be to use prepared statements - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp